# How does combining integer constants work in Android?

Tags: java, android, constants

I am combining a bunch of constants together in Android.

For example, A = 1, B = 2, C = 3

Then I use a function called setParams(A|B|C).

Java converts this to one final int value, say X.

How do I get the individual values from the combined value X, if I only had access to the final combined values of the integer constants?

Comment: can you post some code, it is very unclear what you are doing here

Comment: If you are using a mathematical operation (you didn't specify what you're doing) then it's not possible since there are many different possibilities for the numbers. Example: the result of A*B is 2. A can either be 1 or 2, but you'll never know for sure

Comment: @Michael Therefore I would assume that Java has some sort of internal way of recognizing what the combined values were, correct?

Comment: @Kyle yes, but that would be incorrect. Why are you trying to figure it out this way? If you explicitly pass in the variable to the method, why don't you just store it in a temporary local variable so you can access it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that unless there is a specific rule governing the decomposition.

In your case, since `C` is the same as `A | B`, you can't tell.

If, however, `A`, `B`, and `C` were 1, 2, and 4 respectively (can you see the pattern?), then you could use bitwise arithmetic to extract the constituents from `X`. Doing that is, in fact, common.

Comment: So you mean only Java knows how it was combined, but we won't know what the composition of the combined int constants were?

Comment: @Kyle: Absolutely.

Comment: @Bathsheba It is still not possible to determine how the result was created. for example, given A=1,B=2,C=4, then A|B|C is 7. So Now we ask: given a value of 7 that was created by X|Y|Z, what are X, Y, and Z?  One possible answer is (1,2,4), but (1,1,6) could also be the answer.

Comment: @FredK, indeed *that* is true. But if you know the values of the constituents (part of the "specific rule"), and they are "bitwise exclusive" (if you get my meaning), then you can deduce the constituents.

Comment: This is getting too much into linear algebra and less programming

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering why think that java "must" keep track of things. Why would that be?

The thing is: if you are using variables in your source code, then of course, those live within their scope, like:

```
void foo() {
  int a=5, b=3;
  int c = a * b;
  do something else with a and b
  return c;
```

Of course, even after c is computed, a and b still "exist" and their values can be inspected. But as soon as the method returns, any knowledge about a, b, and c is gone. Then the only thing "left" is the int value of 15 that the method returns.

(and just for the record: in the above example, the compiler would do *constant folding*, and in the byte code for that method, you wouldn't even find a, b, c any more.